# How to add tags/images on javascript fetched textarea data?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, textarea

I have this javascript function that puts a double `--- quote ----` which people can use on the site. My goal is to replace the ---quote--- with a image or a blockquote (styled with CSS) that I already have. So if someone clicks on the button, they have to get a quote image or blockquote, which would be visible on the textarea. The problem is that I can't get it working.

```
<input type="button" onclick="hen('d','--- (<? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?>) ---\n\r','\n\r--- (<? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?>) ---\r')" value="- <? echo $language[quote] ?> -" />
```

This is what I tried for example, which did not show the button anymore.

```
<input type="button" onclick="hen('d','--- (<blockquote id="entry"><? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?></blockquote) ---\n\r','\n\r--- (<? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?>) ---\r')" value="- <? echo $language[quote] ?> -" />
```

How can I make it work my friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you why the button is disappearing at least. You're breaking out of the onclick attribute by listing the blockquote id within double quotes. Try this and see where it gets you:

```
<input type="button" onclick="hen('d','--- (<blockquote id=\'entry\'><? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?></blockquote) ---\n\r','\n\r--- (<? echo $language[quote2] ?>: <? echo $language[quote] ?>) ---\r')" value="- <? echo $language[quote] ?> -" />
```

Although if you're trying to insert HTML elements into a Textarea, I do not believe that is possible. You may want to try using a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` instead (of course, that will only work in browsers that support the contenteditable attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this showed the elements indeed. Is there any other way to output a quote mark in the textarea, just like in TinyMCE editors?

Comment: TinyMCE does not use a textarea for actually handling user input. It uses an `iframe`, with an internal document that is initialized with an empty `<body contenteditable="true"></body>`. The contents of that `body` are then cloned into the textarea (which is hidden) so that they can be submitted with the form.

Comment: TL;DR You will need to use a `contenteditable="true"` element in order to do what you're looking for. [Experiment with this demo](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable); it has the source linked.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer. Is using a iframe with TinyMCE recommended? Because I can use that too if it is handy...

Comment: If your goal is to have a WYSIWYG editor that supports all the same functions of TinyMCE, then sure. TinyMCE in itself is free under the GPL license, so you might as well use it, especially if you're just looking to have the same features.